# Microsoft Azure Graph API for login using certificate thumbprint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am searching for the Microsoft graph API to get login and get token.
What i have got is the API login via client id and client secret.
But i haven't got any API to login using client id and certificate and thumbprint.

Where i have searched for API
*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#endpoint-considerations*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the [Client credentials flow documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for info on this.
Specifically [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate).

Example of the raw request from the docs:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

The main thing that is a bit complicated here is the assertion, which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials).

If you use e.g. MSAL.NET, it's a lot easier though ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications)):

```cs
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .Build();

// Use app object to acquire tokens
```

Comment: that was really helpful.